# Android Maps V2 Memory leak Samsung devices

Tags: android, memory-leaks, google-play-services, google-maps-android-api-2, android-4.4-kitkat

I am banging my head against a brick wall with a memory leak issue that I can reproduce on Samsung devices, at least Galaxy S4, S5 with Android version 4.4.2.

In my app I am using a nested SupportMapFragment in a fragment in a ActionBarActivity with tab navigation set up, that I replace manually with the ChildFragmentManager in onActivityCreated which is the recommended approach for nested fragments.

While zooming and panning for a minute or so, I can see the heap getting bigger and bigger, which finally results in a OOM that crashes my app.
I am working with GroundOverlays and I am aware of Google's advice to not hold on to map objects to prevent memory leaks.

Even after narrowing down by replacing the tab fragment with a SupportMapFragment without any fancy objects, i.e. markers, overlay, etc (and using the latest revision of the v4 support library), I can reproduce the issue debugging on my Samsung S4 device.
I can also reproduce the issue when debugging the sample Google Maps API demos app from Google on my Samsung S4 with Android version 4.4.2.

Especially when selecting the Hybrid maptype, the heap grows fast and it will take around 2 minutes by average before the app crashes.

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
    at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:903)
at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:880)
at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:847)
at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.o.c.l.a(Unknown Source)
at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.o.u.a(Unknown Source)
at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.o.d.c.a(Unknown Source)
at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.o.d.b.a(Unknown Source)
at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.o.l.a(Unknown Source)
at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.o.l.b(Unknown Source)
at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.o.dc.k(Unknown Source)
at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.o.dc.run(Unknown Source)
```

Does anyone have any idea or encountered similar behavior?

Comment: It's not a statement, just added a sentence with a question mark to make that clear.

Comment: Do I get this straight.  You can make the samples crash on a S4?

Comment: I have the very same problem. Since some days our app is crashing for this reason. See also this issue report that describes the same behavior: http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=7187

Comment: @danny117 This is correct.

Comment: I've put on star on the @joluet link.  It will help the issue get swarmed.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this [issue](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=7187&q=apitype%3DAndroid2&sort=-id&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Introduced%20Fixed%20Summary%20Stars%20ApiType%20Internal) that has been acknowledged by Google. It is related to the change that was pushed out with Google Play Services 6.1.09, but it still present with 6.1.11.

People "staring" the issue would help it get fixed.